# How do I get a minilop rabbit accustomed to drinking from a drinking bottle

Tags: training, rabbits, drinking

I just bought a minilop rabbit last week. She is 8 weeks old and this is my first time getting a rabbit, so I have basically no knowledge of looking after rabbits apart from what I know from research and what the pet store told me.

Right now, I have a drinking bottle hung up as well as a small bowl of water. My rabbit has started drinking from the bowl, but has not yet touched the drinking bottle. I'm probably right in assuming she doesn't even know what the bottle is. How do I train her into drinking *from* the bottle?

Comment: Not an answer, but if she doesn't know drinking bottles, she probably has to try it out by accident first. Maybe you can animate her to discover and interact with the bottle?  Make sure the water in the bottle is always fresh and drinkable or you might discourage her from ever drinking from it.

Comment: If the bowl works, you do not need a bottle. In nature rabbits seldom drink. They get all the water needed by fresh greens. Drinking from a bowl is also more natural and less noisy than the ball inside the bottle.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same anxiety with my rabbits but for some reason they automatically learnt to do it so I believe that if you just leave the water in the drinking bottle it will start using it.

Has worked for every rabbit I had.